# What is the jQuery alternative for checkValidity()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just discovered the [JavaScript Validation API](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) `checkValidity()` function.

caniuse.com says this API is available in Firefox and Chrome. I do not need support for other browsers.

Does jQuery provide its own implementation of this API?

Comment: i should add - i dont want to use a jQuery plugin - thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to use the widely used jQuery validation plugin? And if not, use it as plain JS

Comment: This question makes little sense. Just because you are using jQuery “heavily,” does not mean that you can not use normal DOM functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wanting something from Javascript for jQuery?  Just add it to the jQuery namespace like so:

```
$.fn.isValid = function(){
  return this[0].checkValidity()
}
```

Then you can just use `$("#id").isValid()` to return either true/false depending on the validity.

Credit to @Andrew Whitaker.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good. A slight point of criticism being that preliminary code has to be executed to alter that namespace. Offering a second approach, accessing the wanted function via the DOM attached to the jquery object. Use `.get(..)`. E.g., like so:

```js
let form = $('#my_form_to_be_validated');
let is_valid = form.get(0).checkValidity();
```